# Blogger HTML script code scrambled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

After being on the phone all day (both Paypal and Google) I then went to Blogger forums they told me to come here, I hope you can help me.

Paypal offers credit, all you have to do is put the HTML on the page you want to offer credit on and that will put up a button to allow it.  Every time I load the HTML, Blogger scrambles it like eggs and changes the code I'm inserting.

Here's the code that PP gives me, tells me insert before everything on the page which I have done via the HTML button.

I can't figure out how to get all the code in here... it keeps chopping it up during "code sample" input.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-pp-pubid="ee29d99d19" data-pp-
placementtype="190x100"> (function (d, t) {
"use strict";
var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);
n.src = "//paypal.adtag.where.com/merchant.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(n, s);
}(document, "script"));
</script>
```

BLOGGER scrambles to this

```
<script data-pp-placementtype="190x100" data-pp-pubid="ee29d99d19"
type="text/javascript"> (function (d, t) {
"use strict";
var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);
n.src = "//paypal.adtag.where.com/merchant.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(n, s);
}(document, "script"));
</script>
```

So what pops up is just an informational button about PP credit. All other HTML works fine on my pages. Java script is up to date and there's nothing wrong there.  I've tried inserting it in other places, putting it into quotes, etc and nothing has worked so far.

Blogger told me this but it's like another language for me I would like something I can copy and paste into my site and have it work.

You can forward your inquiries to stackoverflow.com and experts there can assist you as you are including 3rd party "extensions" to your Blogger blog which is outside Blogger defined "eco-system".

In a nutshell, Blogger templat-ing is using .XML language & strict which may require you to escape special characters when customizing your theme or adding HTML or javascript codes. In your case wrap your  codes with XML escape directive like so...

```
<script data-*-*="......" data-*-*="......">
//<![CDATA[
```

... your custom javascript codes...

```
//]]>
</script>
```

Use back the tag provided but wrap your codes with the escape directive. You can find in your blog > Template HTML examples shown above used for/at Blogger comments inside your Blog1 widget for reference...

Comment: I don't see any _"code scrambling"_ , the only difference i see between the two code snippets is the rearrangement of the element's attributes which wouldn't affect anything.

Comment: The rearrangement has taken the button from a text to a data? Evidently it keeps the button from working and the only change is that my customers aren't allowed to use PP credit, it's a little big when we are talking about a product that cost $1070 which we have on sale for the Holidays.  I really don't understand all of this and had hoped to have it fixed hours ago.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script data-pp-pubid="ee29d99d19" data-pp-placementtype="190x100" type="text/javascript">
(function (d, t) {
"use strict";
var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);
n.src = "//paypal.adtag.where.com/merchant.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(n, s);
}(document, "script"));
</script>
```

You're dealing with two sources, blogger you have no control over, so your only option is to empirically test various combinations until you find one that seems to work.

Since it appears blogger wants the type="text/javascript" to be at the end of the < script> tag you can try that first.

then, since you don't need that type at all, you can try this:

```
<script data-pp-pubid="ee29d99d19" data-pp-placementtype="190x100">
(function (d, t) {
"use strict";
var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);
n.src = "//paypal.adtag.where.com/merchant.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(n, s);
}(document, "script"));
</script>
```

Trying to reverse engineer a probably badly written parser is not fun, but your only options are to simply try different things and see if one works. It's not blogger's job to handle irregular < script> tags like this, and it's not paypal's job to fix blogger's bugs, though I would think paypal might have some economic incentive to actually test their stuff on blogger since it's a reasonably big platform.

I do not understand why paypal is giving the data-pp-pubid="ee29d99d19" data-pp-placementtype="190x100" inside the < script> tag, usually you assign parameters like that in the actual javascript code, that's how most js embed code I've seen does it, are you sure you copied this right?